# Sphinx + nodejs

Tags: node.js, sphinx

Собратья!) Прошу помощи! Не могу подключиться к поисковому движку Sphinx, используя прекрасный модуль "LimeStone".
Установил Sphinx. Настроил файл конфигурации и так же проиндексировал базу sql.
Если попробовать осуществить поиск в консоли следующим образом - все отлично работает и результат выдается.

```
# search —config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf test
```

На сервере node инициализирую модуль и делаю подключение.

```
var limestone = require('limestone').SphinxClient();

limestone.connect(9312, function(err) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
} else {
console.log('I work!');
}
});
```

При запуске - вылетает сервер и клиентов выбрасывает. 
Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема? Как можно обнаружить источник проблемы? 
Использую последние скаченные версии.

Comment: с какой именно ошибкой вылетает сервер?